# CasperJS doesn't render custom fonts

Tags: encoding, fonts, phantomjs, casperjs, webfonts

I'm using [casperJS](http://casperjs.org/) to take screenshots of different websites. Some websites uses custom fonts such as [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) or [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/). It seems that PhantomJS does not support web fonts and custom fonts.

I'm using

*PhantomJS: version 1.9.8*

*CasperJS: version 1.1.0-beta3*

Every icon/font symbol is replaced with this icon:

[image]

I know the existence of a [unofficial build](http://arunoda.me/blog/phantomjs-webfonts-build.html) for OSX/Linux which has font-face support, but I don't want to use unofficial libraries that are not officially maintained.

Does anyone have any other alternative?

Installing the fonts is not a possibility since the system doesn't know the websites to take the screenshots, could be any, so it means I would need to install all existing fonts.

Thanks in advanced for the help.